# Annoying buzzing noise in earphones connected to my Laptop

Tags: laptop, usb, audio, sound-card, headphones

When I connect an Earphones / Headset to my Laptop (an average ~700€ Laptop) like in the following figure, I get a very annoying random buzzing noise in the Earphones. I can clearly hear it when not playing anything, and also when playing music, video or anything else, in moments where the volume is not high or there is a pause between the instruments, sounds etc.

```
       +------------------------------------+           
       |                                    |           
       |                                    |           
       |                                    |           
       |                                    |           
       |               Laptop               |           
       |                                    |           
       |                                    |           
       |                                    |           
+------+L USB                          R USB+--------+  
|      |                                    |        |  
|      |                               L-OUT+--+     |  
|      +--------------------------------+---+  |     |  
|                                              |     |  
|                                              |     |  
|      +------------------------------------+  |   +---+
+------+                                    |  |   | | |
       |              Keyboard              |  |   +-+-+
       |                                    |  |   |   |
       |                                    |  |   +---+
       +------------------------------------+  |        
                                               |   Mouse
                                               |        
                                               |        
                                               |        
                        +----+                 |        
                       +      +                |        
                       |      |                |        
                      +-+    +-+               |        
                      |-|    |-| +-------------+        
                      +-+    +-+                        

                 Earphones / Headset
```

The questions now are:

- **What is causing the noise ?**
- **Can I fix it, and how ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem is caused by the **low-budget components** (that are common in every *non* top-level Laptop), along with the evidently **insufficient isolation** of the internal electrical circuitery.

Specifically, **the culprit is the optical mouse**, that constantly sends data to the laptop. That data is being somehow involuntarily "intercepted" by the audio circuits, and sent through the wire to the earphones.

The solution I found to overcome this problem is *so* simple that can be considered a [Egg of Columbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_of_Columbus):

simply attach the optical mouse to the USB port in the opposite side of the Laptop, and attach the keyboard near the earphones. The keyboard won't disturb the earphones at all, and the annoying buzzing noise will instantly disappear, never coming back again:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                        |
|  +-------------------------------------------------+   |
|  |                                                 |   |
|  |   +------------------------------------+        |   |
|  |   |                                    |        |   |
|  |   |                                    |        |   |
|  |   |                                    |        |   |
|  |   |                                    |        |   |
|  |   |               Laptop               |        |   |
|  |   |                                    |        |   |
|  |   |                                    |        |   |
|  |   |                                    |        |   |
|  +---+L USB                          R USB+------------+
|      |                                    |        |    
|      |                               L-OUT+--+     |    
|      +--------------------------------+---+  |     |    
|                                              |     |    
|                                              |     |    
|      +------------------------------------+  |   +---+  
+------+                                    |  |   | | |  
       |              Keyboard              |  |   +-+-+  
       |                                    |  |   |   |  
       |                                    |  |   +---+  
       +------------------------------------+  |          
                                               |   Mouse            
                        +----+                 |          
                       +      +                |          
                       |      |                |          
                      +-+    +-+               |          
                      |-|    |-| +-------------+          
                      +-+    +-+                          

                  Earphone / Headset
```

Hope that helps.

Please share your feedbacks whether your case is solved with this solution or not.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but moving the mouse usb port doesn't help, the noise come up randomly... btw I dont have a external keyboard

Comment: Have you removed anything from the usb(s) beside the ear-out port?

Comment: I have read some other acticle, it seems that the problem is with my cheap earphone connectors..

Comment: @Red2awn the problem is absolutely in the cheap hardware components; that's for sure; in my case, however, the earphone connectors alone was NOT noisy, the component itself was not influenced by other internal components near to it; the thing disturbing it was the mouse IF connected. The external keyboard, present or not, was ininfluent. In your case instead, the component seems to be electrically disturbed by something near to it INSIDE the computer, and hence not removable. Too bad, let's hope for the next computer then :/ P.S: feel free to upvote the QUESTION, since it applies to you too.